# smtp mail problem when sending with gmail smtp server from wampserver2 localhost

Tags: email, ssl, smtp

Please ignore, I found the ssl in the php extensions after all. Funny how you find the answer by yourself right after you post.

---

This question is related to development but I think it has to do with admin settings, it might get closed on stackoverflow.

I'm testing code on my local devel environment that should send email through Gmail's smtp server, but I'm getting an error `Unable to connect via TLS` and was wondering what might be the problem.

I'm on wampserver2 and windows. I don't think wampserver2 comes by default with ssl (at least I can't find a php_ssl extension in the list of php extensions). But the code shows that ssl is probably needed. I'm not that familiar with SSL or tweaking the settings for wampserver2. Does anyone have clues what I might need to do to get this working?

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer and accept it. And don't crosspost, if SO think it doesn't fit, they will send it here.

Answer (score 1):

Check smtp host:

```
host: smtp.gmail.com
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465
```

Without the code is hard to say what went wrong.